# jqGrid internationalization

Tags: jqgrid

I need to [i18n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) my [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) depending on the language selected. I need my jqGrid in English and German. What are the steps for the same or how can I achieve it?

Comment: to be more specific... i need the column headers to be changed to specific language when particularlocale is selected....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only the change the column header it is very easy:

```
$('#list').jqGrid ('setLabel', 6, 'Insgesamt');
```

changes the header of the 6-th column to 'Insgesamt'.

Comment: But cant i take this value from the properties file.... i am using spring mvc.... i have used jstl spring tag for internationalization....

Comment: If you construct the values on the server side, than you should have absolutely no problem. Just include in the page the correspond i18n and fill the names of the `colModel` **on the server**. The page which receive the user will at the beginning has all in his language.

Comment: Hey thnx Oleg... But i  find it difficult to understand.... Can u give me some example to simplify it much better????

Comment: @apoorvabade: You don't write which technology you use on the server side (ASP.NET MVC, JSP, PHP and so on). What do you use? It is better if you modify also tags of your question.

Comment: Sure.... Thanks for the information Loeg.. I will keep in mind next time this point.. Sorry for posting it here!!!